# Solr affixes, and words with or without space

Tags: solr, filter

Hungarian language is a bit trickier than English. The words can be altered pretty oddly, which means we need to fine-tune the search if we want to give users a great experience.

I have been doing some research for quite a long time now and I have come across some possible solutions, but I am not sure whether they are suitable for our needs at all. That’s why I’d like to ask for some help from you who are more experienced in using solr.

**I. Words written with or without space**

How is it possible to get the same results, no matter the words are typed with or without space?

Say I am looking for a glass vase ("*üveg váza*” in Hungarian). In Hungarian language it is quite common to write such words together as well. How is it possible to get the same results if someone types the words without space: “*üvegváza*”?
And vica versa, how can I get items with “*üvegváza*” word in it for the search term “*üveg váza*”?

**II. Dealing with affixes, inflection**

In Hungarian language inflection can alter the word itself. For example if you are looking for a "vase with flower decoration", you can say:

- “*virágos váza*” = Vase with flower (closest meaning in English)
- “*váza virággal*” = Vase with flower
- “*váza virágokkal*” = Vase with flowers

What is the best way to deal with inflections? For example if I type “*virág*” how is it possible to give results for “*virágos*”, “*virággal*” as well?
And vice versa: typing the keyword “*virágos*” and get items with the word “*virág*"?

Do you have any advice/idea how we can get these to work?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved ans has solution where you can break down the word into smaller tokens by using `NGramTokenizerFactory`.

Use it like

```
<analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="4" maxGramSize="15"/>
</analyzer>
```

Here if you have input as  `"bicycle"`

then the token created are Out:

```
"bicy", "bicyc", "icyc", "icycl", "cycl", "cycle", "ycle"
```

You can try this `NGramTokenizerFactory` for your field and check it in the solr analysis tool. If it matches your query text.

You can also have a look at the `EdgeNGramTokenizerFactory` which reads the field text and generates edge n-gram tokens of sizes in the given range.

This can be used like

```
<analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.EdgeNGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="5"/>
</analyzer>
```

It has another attribute `side`: (`"front"` or `"back"`, default is `"front"`) Whether to compute the n-grams from the beginning `(front)` of the text or from the end `(back)`.

Input Text: `"babaloo"`
Output Text: `"ba", "bab", "baba", "babal"`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Fragments of words in Hungarian language can often result in completely different or really broad meaning. I'm afraid that this solution would give users too many irrelevant search results. If you have any other idea, I'd be glad if you shared it.

Comment: Its true...fragments may give some odd result...but still I would suggest you to give try in way that apply the analyzer while indexing and not while performing the query. For query use the "KeywordTokenizerFactory". Check it in the solr analysis tool...you can perform or build your own fieldType depending upon your search requirement...

Answer (score 0):

Solr has some-level of Hungarian support. Search for Hungarian on [the solr-start analyzer page](http://www.solr-start.com/info/analyzers/) shows me a complete analyzer, as well as filter. There is also Hungarian support in the Snowball filter. You can see an example configuration in [the TYPO 3 Solr plugin configuration](https://github.com/TYPO3-Solr/ext-solr/tree/master/Resources/Solr/typo3cores/conf/hungarian).

To deal with multi-token vs. single-token way of writing words, you may want to look at the [ShingleFilter](http://www.solr-start.com/javadoc/solr-lucene/org/apache/lucene/analysis/shingle/ShingleFilterFactory.html) with the token separator set to "" (empty string). This may need some experimentation if both text and search can be joined or separated. You may need to enable [autoGeneratePhraseQueries](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Field+Type+Definitions+and+Properties) on the type to get separated word versions to make it to the Query-time ShingleFilter (I think).

Comment: Thank you, we will give these a try.